# Comparison Operators in stored procedures SQL

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, comparison-operators

Hope you can help.

I have this stored procedure. Works fine, but I have problems using comparison operators in my stored procedure. The point here is to find cars who been driving above 10000.

I have been looking for the answer, but for some reason, can't find the solution.

```
elimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE DISTANCE (kilometerafstand INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT bil.registreringsnummer, bil.kilometerstand, biltype.maerke, biltype.model
    FROM bil
    INNER JOIN biltype ON bil.id = biltype.id 
    WHERE bil.kilometerstand = kilometerafstand;
END;

//

call DISTANCE ( > 10000)
```

The code works fine. It's just the operators in my call DISTANCE.

Thank you!

Comment: If you want different kinds of comparisons =, >, < etc, the procedure needs another parameter for that.

Comment: BTW, which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: Ah okay! I am following a course, which I am just doing some things on my own. So the tables were some I made myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just devise the stored procedure to take two parameters, a minimum and maximum:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE DISTANCE (in_min_km INT, in_max_km INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT bil.registreringsnummer, bil.kilometerstand, biltype.maerke, biltype.model
    FROM bil
    INNER JOIN biltype ON bil.id = biltype.id 
    WHERE (bil.kilometerstand >= in_min_km or in_min_km IS NULL) AND
          (bil.kilometerstand <= out_min_km or in_min_km IS NULL);          
END;

//

CALL DISTANCE(10000, NULL) ;
```

Comment: Just saw your reply now. It really makes sense to make! Thank you for your reply! :)

Answer (score 2):

you can't have comparison operator like this. You can have one more parameter

```
 operator varchar
```

and you can have custom logic like `eq`, `ne`, `lt`, `gt`, vice versa. and you can write

```
where (operator = 'eq' and kilometerstand = kilometerafstand )
  or (operator = 'gt' and kilometerstand > kilometerafstand
  or ....
```